# Should I rebind models in ReactiveCocoa MVVM?

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have started setting up my view models so they automatically unbind/bind themselves to any model they represent.

I'm relatively new to ReactiveCocoa and want to know if what I'm doing is bad/good practice or if there's a better way to do it.

For example, if I have a view model that represents a movie model, I would set it up like this:

```
-(void)bind{
    [RACObserve(self, movieModel) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        [self unbindMovieModel];
        [self bindMovieModel];
    }];
}

-(void)unbindMovieModel{}
-(void)bindMovieModel{
    self.titleSignal = [RACObserve(self.movieModel, title) 
        takeUntil:[self rac_signalForSelector:@selector(unbindMovieModel)];

    self.averageRatingSignal = [[self.movieModel currAverageRating] 
        takeUntil:[self rac_signalForSelector:@selector(unbindMovieModel)];

    //Setup some more complex signals, etc...
}
```

Now if at any point I do:

```
self.movieModel = newModel;
```

The view model will unbind from the old movieModel and bind itself to newModel.

Is there a better way? Is this not "reactive"? Any feedback would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drastically simplify this case by moving the `movieModel` from the static to the dynamic part of the `RACObserve` macro:

```
RAC(self.titleLabel, text) = RACObserve(self, movieModel.title);
```

Then, your view will update both when the model instances are exchanged and when a model instance itself changes.

If your view model contains signals itself, you can do something like the following:

```
RAC(self.ratingLabel, text) = [[RACObserve(self, movieModel) map:^(id viewModel) {
    return viewModel.currAverageRating;
}] switchToLatest];
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling I was missing something really basic.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if I'm not using RACObserve? What would you do for the second example where I'm getting the average rating?

Comment: @AkiraSpeirs i've updated my answer to cover this case.

Comment: Thanks so much for that, I just read up about switchToLatest and tested it in my code, it's exactly what I needed!